# VSCode split editors by default

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want (View > Editor Layout > Split Right) by default with every new opened file.

**Preferable behavior:**

If I have one file open - I want the new file to open an editor at the right side of the editor that's already opened. (Split right)

If I open another file afterwards - it should open at the left editor in the place of the first file that was already open.

Then if I open another one it should open at the right editor and so on like a left-right cycle always leaving the penultimate file opened.

If this behavior is not possible what's the closest I can achieve through settings/extensions?

Comment: How are you opening the files - from the explorer, Ctrl+P, or what?

Comment: @Mark I'm opening the files from the VSCode explorer.

Comment: I think I opened a duplicate of this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68850241/change-default-editor-layout-pattern)